# Which commands do work with LOOP-END LOOP statements in SPSS?

Tags: statistics, spss

As you know there are at least 3 ways to loop procedures in SPSS:

1. `DO REPEAT-END REPEAT`
2. `LOOP-END LOOP`
3. `!DO-!DOEND` structure inside `DEFINE-!ENDDEFINE` macro definition.

Now I'm asking about the second option. This kind of loop is more simple to use yet its functionality is significantly lesser than especially inside `!DO-!DOEND` structure.

**Does anybody know which commands do work with `LOOP-END LOOP` and which doesn't? I tried to find a complete list but I haven't found anything.**

Comment: your question is quite large in scope, as SPSS has probably thousands of commands available, and I am not sure an exhaustive list of "those which work" is the answer you are lookign for. Furthermore, I am not sure if stackoverflow is the right place to ask this; perhaps if you can present your real problem you are trying to solve...? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: you could start with the official SPSS documentation on LOOP: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLVMB_26.0.0/statistics_reference_project_ddita/spss/base/syn_loop_overview.html

Comment: @horace_vr: sadly, I didn't have any problem to solve that time :(. I was just looking for a list because I had tried to use `LOOP` so many times but it hadn't work. Now I think an answer published by Reywood (below) pretty much explains this issue.

I've also simply thought such a list is somewhere in the Internet and I'd just couldn't find it. Thanks anyway for comments :).

Answer (score 0):

Konrad,
As others have mentioned it is good to copnsult the SPSS Statistics Documentation.  In this case, the SPSS Statistics Command Syntax Reference Guide is the one I'd choose.

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLVMB_26.0.0/statistics_reference_project_ddita/spss/base/syn_commands_and_program_states_procedures.html

Briefly, the looping constructs you've mentioned all operate on Transformational commands -- commands that alter the data but do not require a read of the data.  Transformations (e.g. COMPUTE, RECODE, SELECT IF, etc.) stack up in memory and take effect when an EXECUTE or a procedure command cause a data read.

If what you are looking to do is to iterate procedural commands (e.g. FREQUENCIES, REGRESSION, GGRAPH, etc.), that can be accomplished through the DEFINE--!ENDDEFINE command language, or better still through a Python script.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Okay, I simply couldn't understand the philosophy of ```LOOP-END LOOP``` and transformational vs. procedural commands (even though I understand English). I've also thought there is a list of commands which work with ```LOOP``` and I simply can't find it. Thanks!